# Netbeans runs old code

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Netbeans project on a flash drive so I can move from computer to computer to code. On one computer running the project works fine, but on the other computer if I make any changes to my source code then run the project, it uses the old code. If I do a `clean` on the code, and then run it, it uses the changes. How can I get it to stop doing that, and use the changes automatically when I run the project?

Comment: if you try a sample with Eclipse, are you getting same error?

Comment: I'm not sure if its relevant, but you may want to post what filesystem you use on your drive. I'm thinking certain file statistics aren't supported/tracked that netbeans relies on.

Comment: I am using FAT32 on Windows 8. The only difference between the two computers is the OS.

Comment: Did you turn on "compile on save" for that project? If yes, try turning it off.

Comment: I tried doing a Complete re-install (Uninstalling prefs/plugins), and so far it seems like it is working.

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.2, I haven't had problems with it anymore since I did a complete re-install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as doing a complete re-install fixed the problems. By complete I mean uninstall Netbeans and all of the the settings/preferences/plugins.